# Get data from sub collections document from firestore using PHP?

Tags: php, google-cloud-firestore

I am new in firestore. I can't retrieve sub collections document output using PHP.

```
Demo [collection]
     Demo123
             Test [collection]
                              Test1
                              Test2
                              Test3
                                field : 1,
                                field : 2
```

I use following command :

```
$database->collection('Demo')
                ->document('Demo123')
                ->collection('Test')
                ->document(Test3);
```

output of the following code : null.

Answer (score 0):

You literally missed the quotes in the last line